# Converting a string List to a custom List

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to call a web service, and hitting a road block.

Here's a snippet in which I call the said web service in a console application to test (this works):

```
        WSProxy.CancelOrderClient x = new CancelOrderClient(); 
        WSProxy.OrderCancelObject y = new OrderCancelObject(); 

        var z = new List<OrderNumberObject>();
        var p = new OrderNumberObject();
        p.OrderNumber = "100";
        z.Add(p);

        y.OrderNumberTbl = z.ToArray();
        y.StoreNumber = "700";

        var a = x.CancelOrder(y);
        Console.WriteLine(a.ExResultMessage.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(a.ExResultMessage.Code);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I want to put this in a separate static method to which the inputs are a `List<string>` for order numbers and a string for `StoreNumber`.

Each OrderNumberObject has just one string property, which is the OrderNumber ***which is of type string***.

Given this context, I don't know how to convert/cast the `List<string>` to a `List<OrderNumberObject>`, where `OrderNumberObject` has a property called `OrderNumber`.

How do we do that? Unfortunately I have no freedom to modify the said web service I'm trying to call.

Hopefully that explained what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you added a linq tag try something like below:

```
ListOfStrings.Select(s => new OrderNumberObject() { OrderNumber=s}).ToList();
```

edit:

```
(from s in ListOfStrings
 select new OrderNumberObject() {OrderNumber = s}
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you @seven21. What does this expression look like with LINQ query syntax?

Answer (score 2):

```
        var SomeListOfStrings = new List<string>(); //The list of strings that you received from your service call or whatever. I just created it here, but you would have got it from somewhere... 

        var orderNumbers = new List<OrderNumberObject>();

        foreach (var str in SomeListOfStrings)
        {
            //I am assuming the order number is a string property. 
            orderNumbers.Add(new OrderNumberObject {OrderNumber=str});
        }
```

I dont believe you need to do any casting if the OrderNumberObject.OrderNumber is a string, given you are receiving a string and storing it as a string.